# write vba to auto filter between two values giving error

Tags: excel, autofilter

I have written code as below to filter a percentage field between two different values coming from two different fields:

Please find below:

These two values are numbers and the filter column is percentage.
**I get the following error: AutoFilter method of Range class failed**

```vb
With ActiveSheet.Range("A5:G" & LastRow)
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=">=" & Worksheets("Project % Spent").Range("K5").Value, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Worksheets("Project % Spent").Range("K6").Value
End With
```

Can anyone please help me out with what I should mention exactly?

Comment: What values are in the ranges you're referencing? The syntax of your VBA code appears to be correct, so it's probable that there's something going wrong when you're trying to reference other values

Comment: Hi , filetr values are 10%,0%,20%,39% etc and the values which i refer to is 10.19
-9.81
So i wanted to flter which is >10.19 and <-9.81 , and this reference value is dynamic not constant.

Comment: OK, a couple of things to be aware of then - using `.Value` on 10% will return 0.1, not 10. Also, you can't have a number greater than 10.19, but less than -9.81. Try switching < and > maybe?

Comment: Yes , i changed the reference to Percentage and interchanged < and > and it worked like magic! Thank you so much !

Comment: Hi @dhumphreys , is there a way where i do not want to show in between these two values?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean...you mean you want to filter to show everything not in between two values?

Comment: Sorry! i didn't see your comment. I wanted to filter to show everything not in between two values?

Comment: If one value will always be bigger than the other, then you could just filter to show everything bigger then the biggest value, and everything smaller than the smallest value?

Comment: okay can you share syntax?

Comment: Depends on what `Range` contains the biggest value. `Criteria1:= ">" & "biggerValue"` and `Criteria2:= "<" & "smallerValue"` Just substitute `biggerValue` and `smallerValue` with the relevant `Worksheets.Range` reference

Comment: I tired the same but it is not giving any data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .Value on 10% will return 0.1, not 10. Also, you can't have a number greater than 10.19, but less than -9.81. Try switching < and > and the code will work.